# How to remove port number from url in production server in django project?

Tags: python, django

I am deploying my project in production server but the port number is coming in the url.
So is there any way to remove the port number from url in Django

http://domain_name:8586/admin/login?next=/

Comment: Is your app deployed behind a reverse proxy/webserver like nginx or apache?

Comment: you need to user reverse proxy with nginx + gunicorn + django for it

Comment: How are you running your django app on the production server? The server configuration will specify the port. Just don't use a custom port and you won't need to specify a port in the URL.

Comment: p.s. Don't use `manage.py runserver` in production. This is only intended for development and is not secure enough for a production server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change django's default port to 80. Because all browsers(clients) will test port 80 if you don't enter any port

Comment: Or 443 if you use https. HTTP port 80 and HTTPS port 443 is standard and dont need to be added to url

Answer (score 1):

If you run your app on port 80 (the default port for http) you won't need to write the port number to access it.

Any client (browser) will try port 80 if no port number was specified.

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

in_url = "http://domain_name:8586/admin/login?next=/"

parser_url = urlparse(in_url)
out_url = parser_url._replace(netloc=parser_url.netloc.replace(str(parser_url.port), "")).geturl()
print(out_url)
```

Comment: You should also explain the answer little bit.